# Python Logging with timezone in

Tags: python, python-logging

I have a Python app running on a server that is not in the the local timezone.

Everything works fine but when it runs on the server it's providing the log timestamp with a different timezone.

Ideally I would want it to show in local time which should be GMT.

What I initially had is:

```
logging.basicConfig(
handlers=[RotatingFileHandler(file_loc + "\\" + logfile_nme, maxBytes=500000, backupCount=1)],
level=logging.INFO,
format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

I've tried various online methods of either:

```
logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime
```

Also I tried this:

```
def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
ct_local = time.localtime(record.created)
ct_gmt =  time.gmtime(record.created)
if datefmt:
    s = time.strftime(datefmt, ct_local) + '\t[' + time.strftime(datefmt, ct_gmt) + ']'
else:
    t_local = time.strftime(self.default_time_format, ct_local)
    t_gmt = time.strftime(self.default_time_format, ct_gmt)
    s = self.default_msec_format % (t_local, record.msecs) + '\t[' + self.default_msec_format % (t_gmt, record.msecs) + ']' 
return s
```

But wasn't sure how to apply that to logging as a formatter...

Would appreciate any input.

Thanks,
Shane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could benefit of the time-zone in the date/time format

```
'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S%z'
```

This will output

```
... 15:41:10+0100 INFO ....
```

Comment: Thanks, that is great. Is there a way to have it show as:

... 15:41:10 TZ+0100GMT INFO ....